# Convert from char* to NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

What is the best way to convert from `char *` to an instance of `NSString`?
I used the method `-stringWithUTF8String:`, but it's not good: the result contains "\n" at the end!

Comment: That method doesn't add a trailing \n - if the resulting NSString had one, it's because the C string you started with had one.

Answer (score 3):

Create the string using the same method you're using now. Then, use a method like `-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` to create the trimmed string that you really want.

Comment: But what if you want to retain other `'\n's` that might appear in the middle of the string?

Comment: Trim only removes them at the beginning and end, not in the middle

Comment: Read the description of `-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`... "Returns a new string made by removing from both ends of the receiver characters contained in a given character set." Any newlines in the middle of the string are safe.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an actual code example to **Convert from char* to NSString**, as there was none in the other answer(s). For example with `toBeConverted` a `char*`:

```
NSString *convertedValue = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: toBeConverted];
```

Comment: I posted this after having the same question as the original title, even though I didn't care about the mentioned `\n`. As the question and answer didn't contain a code example, I had to look elsewhere on how to actually do this. Hope this helps others in the same situation.